# npm start -- tsc -w exited with code 126

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-start

`npm -v` : `3.10.8`

`node -v`: `v4.5.0`

After cloning the [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) (having karma and jasmine) By using the commands,`git clone .....`, `npm install`, `npm start`. It returns the following error code:

```
$ npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Ivar\documents\school\stage\workspace\v2\quickstart
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"

[0] /c: /c: is a directory
[1] /c: /c: is a directory
[0] tsc -w exited with code 126
[1] lite-server exited with code 126

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ivar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ivar\documents\school\stage\workspace\v2\quickstart\npm-debug.log
```

**Debug.log**

```
$ cat npm-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Ivar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.8
3 info using node@v4.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Ivar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Ivar\documents\school\stage\workspace\v2\quickstart\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Ivar\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Ivar\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;C:\Users\Ivar\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Android;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\gradle-3.0\bin;C:\Ruby21-x64\bin;C:\Users\Ivar\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Ivar\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Ivar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
10 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Ivar\documents\school\stage\workspace\v2\quickstart
11 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" ' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ivar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ivar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\Ivar\documents\school\stage\workspace\v2\quickstart
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ivar\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v4.5.0
20 error npm  v3.10.8
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular-quickstart
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Also created an issue on angular/quickstart (https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/234) but figured this might be a problem concerning my setup instead of a problem with the quickstart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting all existing node_modules and reinstalling them with `npm install` worked here.